# How to connect to S3 bucket without providing Access and Secret keys in code with Keystonejs?

Tags: amazon-s3, keystonejs

I have already tried using few keystonejs adapters : keystone-storage-adapter-s3 ,keystone-s3-upload-adapter.
But Access and Secret keys are required parameters in these adapters.
**I want to connect to the bucket using IAM roles.**
This is the code for adapter which doesn't allow access without Access and Secret keys or with IAM roles.

```
adapter: require('keystone-storage-adapter-s3'),
  s3: {
    key: 's3-key', // required; defaults to process.env.S3_KEY 
    secret: 'secret', // required; defaults to process.env.S3_SECRET 
    bucket: 'mybucket', // required; defaults to process.env.S3_BUCKET 
    path: '/profilepics',
    headers: {
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read', // add default headers; see below for details 
    },
```